# Regex pattern between symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a data object like this

```
var myData = {
    "birthYear" : "1956",
    "name" : "Bryan Lee Cranston"
    "birthPlace" : "California"
}
```

And a variable like this

```
var myInfoText = #name# born #birthYear#, is an actor, and producer. He is best known for #best_known#";
```

Now I need a function to check for #sample# pattern in myInfoText. If it find this pattern in it than will check myData object properties for this key and replace myInfoText variable with the help of this property value.

Finally I am expecting something like this:

**Bryan Lee Cranston** born **1956** is an actor, and producer. He is best known for #best_known#";

I know I can do it with regex but belive me no matter how hard I try I did not understand anything with this regex thing. Thank you.

Comment: please share your hard work :P... i.e your code.. what you have tried.

Comment: this is best pattern I have achieved so far `var regExp = /#([^)]+)#/;` But It gets only 1 match from the sentence and acts like #<--name# born #birthYear--># is a match.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
function parseTemplate(str, data){
  return str.replace(/#([^#]+)#/g, function($0, $1){ 
   return data.hasOwnProperty($1) ? data[$1] : $0; 
  })
}
```

Now, using this function with your example:

```
parseTemplate('#name# born #birthYear#, is an actor, and producer. He is best known for #best_known#', {
 "birthYear" : "1956",
 "name" : "Bryan Lee Cranston",
 "birthPlace" : "California"
});
```

Will return:

```
"Bryan Lee Cranston born 1956, is an actor, and producer. He is best known for #best_known#"
```

Comment: Well, there are some caveats to this solution: when the `data[$1]` contains values such as `""`, it will bounce back to the template string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery, you can loop through the object like so:

```
var myData = {
    "birthYear" : "1956",
    "name" : "Bryan Lee Cranston",
    "birthPlace" : "California"
};
var myInfoText = '#name# born #birthYear#, is an actor, and producer. He is best known for #best_known#';

$.each(myData, function(key, value) {
    var regex = new RegExp('#' + key + '#', 'g');
    myInfoText = myInfoText.replace(regex, value);
});

console.log(myInfoText);
```

Without jQuery, you'll need to loop through the object a different way.  The important part is the regular expression in the callback function.

**Edit:** I added a global modifier to the `RegExp`, in case there are duplicate keys (thanks @h2ooooooo).

Comment: [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question). Don't use jQuery just to use jQuery when a `for` loop can do the exact same.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, I'll be honest..I slacked.  But this is why I made a point to needed jQuery for this actually to work.  I was letting OP modify my answer to make it work for his environment (so he/she learned along the way).  The bulk of the answer has to do with the `RegExp` and `String.replace()`.  Valid comment, nonetheless.

Comment: Fair enough. This solution wouldn't work if there's more than one template key, though. (`new Regex(regex, 'g')` would fix that though)